# Dynamically adding html from external view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function in javascript appending some HTML to some div like:

```
$("#test").html("<tr><td>" + data[0].foo + "</td></tr>");
```

I don't want this HTML to be in my code, so I want to place this into some external file and load it into variable. But what about data variable? How do I pass it to this external file? How do I use it?

Answer (score 1):

You can store that code in a file (let's say `script.js` because I'm feeling creative), and using the jQuery function `$.getScript( "script.js")` will load the script into your page. 
If you have the name in a variable, that's not a problem, you can just use

```
var scriptSrc="script.js";
$.getScript(scriptSrc);
```

Does this answer your question?